# Converting object to an encodable object failed in http call

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

I'm getting a response from API but there is an error.
I'm not getting any response where I'm calling topicpurchased()

```
Future<bool> topicpurchased(int topicid, String title) async {
  var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
  map['topicid'] = topicid;
  map['title'] = title;
  var data = json.encode(map);
  print(data);
  var response = await http.post(Constants.ApiBaseUrl + '/topicpuchased',
      headers: headers, body: data);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print("topicpurchasede" + response.body);
    TrueOrFalse trueOrFalse = TrueOrFalse.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    if (trueOrFalse.status == "sucess") {
      print(" ");
      return true;
    } else {
      print("something went wrong" + trueOrFalse.status);
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed');
  }
}
```

error in console as follows

```
I/flutter (22130): topicpurchasede{"status":"sucess"}
I/flutter (22130): datamodel sucess
I/flutter (22130):  
E/flutter (22130): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'Future<String>'
E/flutter (22130): #0      _JsonStringifier.writeObject (dart:convert/json.dart:688:7)
E/flutter (22130): #1      _JsonStringifier.writeMap (dart:convert/json.dart:769:7)
E/flutter (22130): #2      _JsonStringifier.writeJsonValue (dart:convert/json.dart:724:21)
E/flutter (22130): #3      _JsonStringifier.writeObject (dart:convert/json.dart:679:9)
E/flutter (22130): #4      _JsonStringStringifier.printOn (dart:convert/json.dart:877:17)
E/flutter (22130): #5      _JsonStringStringifier.stringify (dart:convert/json.dart:862:5)
E/flutter (22130): #6      JsonEncoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:262:30)
E/flutter (22130): #7      JsonCodec.encode (dart:convert/json.dart:172:45)
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: put code where your calling topicpurchased();

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to call the function using await because it's a Future:

Example:

```
bool response = await topicpurchased(topicid,title);
```

```js
Future<bool> topicpurchased(int topicid, String title) async {
  var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
  map['topicid'] = topicid;
  map['title'] = title;
  var data = json.encode(map);
  print(data);
  var response = await http.post(Constants.ApiBaseUrl + '/topicpuchased',
      headers: headers, body: data);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print("topicpurchasede" + response.body);
    //here could be the bug
    TrueOrFalse trueOrFalse = TrueOrFalse.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    if (trueOrFalse.status == "sucess") {
      print(" ");
      return true;
    } else {
      print("something went wrong" + trueOrFalse.status);
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    //second: here too you can send a bool return because you function has declare a 
    //bool response
    throw Exception('Failed');
  }
}
```

Third: The error seems to come from your model, you can comment on this line and run the application to see if the error comes from there

Comment: i tried it and also this  
await topicpurchased(topicid,title).them((res)=>{
print(res);
});

both didn't work